# Javascript and jQuery error in fetching data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I have started learning javascript and i wrote a piece of code below.

```
var dataFetch = $.getJSON("http://localhost:12345/stream", function (Data) {
    alert(Data);
    $.each( Data, function () {
        alert(this);
        $("<li>").html(this.rss).prependTo(tweetList);
    });
});

dataFetch.done(function () {
    alert("done");
});
dataFetch.fail(function () {
    alert("fail");
});
```

When i put the link `http://localhost:12345/stream` in the broswer i get:

```
{"rss":{"version":"2.0","channel":{"title":"Dave Winer","link":"http://scripting.com/","description":"Dave Winer&apos;s \"Scripting News\" weblog, started in April 1997, bootstrapped the blogging revolution.","language":"en-us","copyright":"Copyright 2012 Scripting News, Inc.","pubDate":"Mon, 08 Oct 2012 04:00:00 GMT","lastBuildDate":"Mon, 08 Oct 2012 18:12:27.... 
........... much more here
```

But when i run this html file, i get the *failure with alert dialog box of fail*.

I am sending the data on the localhost by `JSON.stringify(some_json_object).` from a node.js server code.

What is the error ?

Comment: open your console to see the error

Comment: Have you added this header in your nodejs server 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'?? It might be a CORS issue..

Comment: try modifying ur callback as dataFetch.fail(function (error) {
    alert("Error is " + error);
});

Comment: @iBlue. That shows Error is [object]? Is there something link error.msg ?

Comment: I got that: Error is "readyState":"4", status:404, statusText:error

Comment: try error.responseText

Comment: @theGreatDanton i put response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/plain","Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"}); in my createServer function. same 404 error with readyState 4

Comment: I think CORS works. Thanks theGreatDanton

Answer (score 0):

Putting "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*" in the response header of `createServer` function solved the problem :

```
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/plain",
                         "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"});
```

This allows everyone to access this endpoint of my server. One can put an ip address or name of domain too in place of * to allow only a particular client to access this.